# change the result of query

Tags: mysql, yii

there is anyway to change the result of a query, I have several columns in my database's table with 1 and 0 values, but the 1s and 0s have meaning , let's say 1=Can Jump 0=Don't jump,

I make to query using the code below, and it will gives me back the columns with the 0s and 1s, there is anyway easy to change this values to can jump / dont jump , I'm guessing like an filter or something....

```
public function search()
    {
        // @todo Please modify the following code to remove attributes that should not be searched.

        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

        $criteria->compare('id',$this->id,true);
        $criteria->compare('result',$this->result,true);
        $criteria->compare('p_city',$this->p_city,true);
        $criteria->compare('p_state',$this->p_state,true);
        $criteria->compare('d_city',$this->d_city,true);
        $criteria->compare('d_state',$this->d_state,true);      
        $criteria->compare('type',$this->type,true);
        $criteria->compare('date_search',$this->date_search,true);
        $criteria->compare('date_shipped',$this->date_shipped,true);
        $criteria->compare('driveable',$this->driveable,true);
        $criteria->compare('enclosing',$this->enclosing,true);
        $criteria->compare('type_service',$this->type_service,true);
                $criteria->order='date_search desc';
        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
        ));
    }
```

Comment: you need to use a "where" clause

Comment: or you can use http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-string-functions.htm#function_replace

Comment: you can make a look up table with values like 'jump', 'canJump' having unique Id`s. put this primary in your model and use relations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using the `afterFind` function in your model:

```
public function afterFind() {
    $this->driveable == '1' ? 'Yes' : 'No';
}
```

Comment: Michiel, thanks for your answer, this function will be triggered automatically by yii???, or should I execute it after $model->search() ???, can you be a more explicit????

Comment: I did forgot to include [this link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#afterFind-detail). It states the following: `This method is invoked after each record is instantiated by a find method.`. Yii will do this automaticly for you.